# Specifying "from" email address when sending mail from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using gmail to manage the email for my rails app domain.

The google account is, say, account_owner@gmail.com

But the "from" email address should be, say, info@mysite.com

When I configure `smtp_settings` as below, the email is sent, but the "from" email address is account_owner@gmail.com. I want it to be info@mysite.com, but if I change the `:user_name` to info@mysite.com and its password, my app seems to send the email, but it is never received. How can I achieve this?

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "account_owner@gmail.com",
  :password             => "thepassword",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to hide your actual GMail and pretend it's coming from info@mysite.com? Or do you actually want to change it to you use some other email you've set up? You definitely won't be able to use `stmp.gmail.com` then, or the `gmail.com` domain. Maybe even the port will be different. You'll have to set it up to use the SMTP server's settings.

Comment: Actually info@mysite.com is the primary email address for my business gmail account. account_owner@gmail.com seen in my question is actually another gmail account I have that is not associated with the info@mysite.com account, except for being the recovery email. So I would think info@mysite.com would work.

Comment: When I do specify info@mysite.com as the :user_name, the rails log shows the email sent successfully, but it is never received.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the "from" address when sending mail via Gmail. (Unless maybe if you've configured that account to have other "send as" addresses, though I've never tested it)

I would suggest trying the free hosted Gmail for your domain, or use a third-party service like Mandrill.com

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't specify it as `:user_name` in your `smtp_settings`. Instead you should set the `:from` option like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'info@mysite.com'
```

Alternatively you can set the from address when you send the email:

```
mail(:to => 'info@theirsite.com', :from => 'info@mysite.com' :subject => '...')
```